# Error when sending SMS through PHP with shell_exec() command

Tags: php, gammu

I tried to execute this command from shell_exec() function in php and I get some error output :

Warning: No configuration file found! Warning: No configuration read, using builtin defaults! Error opening device, it doesn't exist.

But, when I try to do it directly inside the command prompt, it works.
I already check all the configuration files in Gammu and found no mistakes.
So, what do I probably wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

When executing from PHP, you're most likely executing the program as different user, thus it can not see your configuration. Either copy the Gammu configuration to the PHP user home or specify path to configuration on the command line:

```
gammu --config /path/to/gammurc ...
```